# Dropped Bike on Left Side and now It Won't Start if in Gear

Tags: honda, clutch

My 2012 Honda CBR250RR dropped on its left side today.
I tried to start it after, but it won't start unless I put it in neutral.

I thought the side stand switch may be the problem, but even if I try to pull-in the clutch while in 1st-gear and start the bike -usually it should start- nothing happens, as if I'm not pressing the start button. This used to happen if I try to start the bike with my gear engaged and without pulling the clutch, but now it seems like the bike cannot sense pulling the clutch.

I start the bike in **N**, but  once I engage 1st gear it jerk and stalls. 
Is this a clutch problem?

I tried revving to high while in N then put in the 1st gear, still it stalls.

What happened?

Comment: Is the bike a CBR250R (single R)? There doesn't seem to be such a thing as a CBR250RR.

Comment: http://autos.maxabout.com/bikes/honda/cbr250r/cbr250rr it appears to be a bit like a CBR250R on steroids, non-european model and certainly a range I was unfamiliar with but they do appear to exist.  The 2017 version is a real looker.

Comment: @SteveMatthews That link says, "The ‘Light Weight Super Sport Concept’ (CBR250RR) was unveiled earlier at the 2015 Tokyo Motor Show."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all likelihood, your side stand switch was damaged. The bike will not allow itself to start or run in gear with the side stand down. It doesn't matter if the clutch is in or not, as there is no circumstance when you'd want to be in gear with the side stand down. Check the motion of the side stand and that it's interfacing with the switch properly. The switch on your bike seems to have a wheel and teeth that grab the side stand and move with it. It's quite possible these teeth are damaged and the switch isn't moving as it should. If you have a multimeter you can check the switch for continuity. It should beep when the side stand is up, and not when it is down. Alternatively, you can try disconnecting the side stand switch and bridging the connection to see if that fixes it.

If the problem persists, it's also possible your clutch lever or cable were damaged, and the clutch is not fully engaging. Have a look at the engine side cover when you pull the clutch lever. Is the cable significantly moving the actuator? ([#16 on the diagram](http://www.partzilla.com/parts/search/Honda/Motorcycle/2012/CBR250R+AC/RIGHT+CRANKCASE+COVER/parts.html)). The cable should be pulling it and moving it roughly the same amount that the cable pulls at the lever, across the entire range of motion. If there is too much slack, the cable is broken, or it's movement is restricted or uneven, your clutch won't engage properly.

The other possibility is your clutch switch was damaged. The switch is located on the clutch lever, and allows the motorcycle to know if the clutch is engaged or not. This is how it prevents you from starting the bike in gear unless the sidestand is up and the bike is in neutral. Check if you can start the bike in neutral, and with the sidestand up. If so, that could indicate a problem with this switch.

Comment: thanks infact it was the clutch switch, i removed it and now bike back to life :).. thanks

Comment: Nice work. Just be careful when starting your bike now that you're not in gear. If you are, the bike will jump forward when you hit the starter button. You should be able to pick up even a brand new replacement for very little cost.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how long it was on it's side, the clutch hydraulics may need bleeding.  My guess is air is in the hydraulic line so pulling the clutch lever isn't correctly disengaging the clutch.

Comment: The CBR250R, like most small bikes, has a cable operated clutch. http://www.partzilla.com/parts/search/Honda/Motorcycle/2012/CBR250R+AC/HANDLE+LEVER+%2B+SWITCH+%2B+CABLE/parts.html

Comment: I did wonder about that but first googled for CBR250RR hydraulic clutch and it came back with a universal replacement clutch lever which included a hydraulic reservoir so I assumed it must by hydraulic from that.  The CBR250RR is a non-European market model from what I could find.

Comment: I could be wrong, but the only CBR250RRs that I know of are from the 90s, or have just recently been introduced to the market. 2012 makes me think it's a single R version.

Answer (score 0):

I always remember bikes only started in neutral (safety as a high power to weight ratio) - could your isolator switch have been incorrectly set before allowing it to start in neutral and now, after dropping it, it is where it should be.

Answer (score 0):

> I start the bike in N, but once I engage 1st gear it jerk and stalls. Is this a clutch problem?

Just from what you said there it sounds like it could be a clutch problem. But before we go down that road like others have said it could be the side stand switch too. I had an old bike with a sticky side stand switch, and even when the side stand was up and I kicked it into gear, the bike would just shut off. The switch looked like it operated as it should, it was pressed down when the stand was down and extended out when the stand was put away, but I fond out the switch wasn't fully extending, and I had to use my fingers or some pliers to pull it out another centimeter so it would fully disengage and allow me into gear. This could be your problem, I would check and see if it's sticky before going on to clutch diagnosis. If it is the clutch, I would check the cable, check how taught it is and how much the clutch disengages when you pull the lever. Good luck